# A new user belonging to a new application role doesnt' see Create Report option in OBIEE

Tags: oracle, security, obiee, bi-publisher, publisher

Our team has recently created a new user `fb_user` that belongs to a new group `FB_USERS`. From EM we created a new application role `BIFbRole` using '`Create like`' option on `BIContentAuthor` role. The group `FB_USERS` is added as members of the new role.

However when this user logs into OBIEE and clicks 'New' button, he sees only options to create an Analyses, Dashboard, Filter, Dashboard promt, Condition, KPI and Agent. That is he is not able to create a Publisher Report or Data Model or Mobile App.

We couldn't find an option to enable this in 'Manage Priveleges' section of OBIEE. We know that BIContentAuthor role has `publisher.developReport` and `publisher.developDataModel` permissions, but wouldn't creating a new role using `Create like` on `BIContentAuthor` automaticall assign this permission to newly created role?

Have anyone faced this kind of issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the second half of what makes up security: Application Policies. They're also in EM and they control access to DV, BI Publisher etc.

Comment: Thanks @Chris for the reply. As you said, there is an application policies section in EM. I tried to edit BIContentAuthor policy and add this new role as a grantee, but in this case it is not adding it as a new grantee to the end of the list but replacing BIContentAuthor with new role.  
Then I tried to create a new policy by clicking 'Create Like' on BIContentAuthor. Added the new role to this policy, clicked OK, then a message pops up about successful creation, but I don't see that new policy, the list remains unchanged for some reason.

Comment: It should look like this: https://youtu.be/JUCZwQOmBn8?t=1593

Comment: Thanks, I created (not by 'Create like') a new policy for the new role and it worked.